# How to fix this gettallheaders.php error in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, optimization

I am making a laravel instragram clone website but suddenly after some development When i run php artisan serve this error occurs .

> PHP Warning:  require(I:\LARAVEL\laravel-instagram-clone\vendor\composer/../ralouphie/getallheaders/src/getallheaders.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in I:\LARAVEL\laravel-instagram-clone\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 66
>
> Warning: require(I:\LARAVEL\laravel-instagram-clone\vendor\composer/../ralouphie/getallheaders/src/getallheaders.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in I:\LARAVEL\laravel-instagram-clone\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 66
>
> PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'I:\LARAVEL\laravel-instagram-clone\vendor\composer/../ralouphie/getallheaders/src/getallheaders.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in I:\LARAVEL\laravel-instagram-clone\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 66
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'I:\LARAVEL\laravel-instagram-clone\vendor\composer/../ralouphie/getallheaders/src/getallheaders.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in I:\LARAVEL\laravel-instagram-clone\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 66
>
> I:\LARAVEL\laravel-instagram-clone>php artisan serve
>   PHP Warning:  require(I:\LARAVEL\laravel-instagram-clone\vendor\composer/../ralouphie/getallheaders/src/getallheaders.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in I:\LARAVEL\laravel-instagram-clone\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 66
>
> Warning: require(I:\LARAVEL\laravel-instagram-clone\vendor\composer/../ralouphie/getallheaders/src/getallheaders.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in I:\LARAVEL\laravel-instagram-clone\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 66
>   PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'I:\LARAVEL\laravel-instagram-clone\vendor\composer/../ralouphie/getallheaders/src/getallheaders.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in I:\LARAVEL\laravel-instagram-clone\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 66
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'I:\LARAVEL\laravel-instagram-clone\vendor\composer/../ralouphie/getallheaders/src/getallheaders.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in I:\LARAVEL\laravel-instagram-clone\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 66

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems composer dependencies are missing.

Open terminal, browse to root of the project directory then Try run.

`composer install`

Comment: Yeah i did that but somehow that was not working .Then i delete the whole vendor folder then run composer install , then its working fine . Thanks !

Comment: I've tried with php v7.1 and it's successful; but with v7.2, it doesn't install the `ralouphie/getallheaders` package.